# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de utilizar, validar y procesar **kwargs?

Tags: python, validación

Buen día,

He estado haciendo varias pruebas e investigado sobre varias estrategias para utiliza, validar y procesar kwargs pero no he encontrado nada que explique por qué una estrategia es mejor o más segura

Para esto cree una clase `A` que recibe `kwargs` y tiene un método `b` (El código en sí no tiene sentido pero es suficiente para explicar mis dudas)

Una estrategia es declarar todos los kwargs en el `__init__` tal y como está en el siguiente ejemplo

```
class A(object):
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            self.__setattr__(k, v)
        print(self.b(self.c,self.d))
    
    def b(self,c,d):
        return(c+d)
```

Si utilizamos la clase de la siguiente forma:

```
prueba = A(c=1, d=8)
```

El código imprime `9` al ejecutar el `__init__` de la clase A. El problema es que si no se incluye `c` o `d` el código falla ya que no existiría `self.c` o `self.d` para el método `b`.

Otro problema es que si pasamos `b` como argumento, al procesar los `kwargs` esto sobreescribiría el método `b`

```
prueba = A(b=5, c=1, d=8)
```

Y regresa el error:

```
 'int' object is not callable
```

Ya que `self.b` ahora es `5` en lugar del método interno de la clase.

Para corregir el primer problema se podrían inicializar los valores de `c` y `d` para que el método `self.b()` siempre reciba los argumentos que necesita

```
class A(object):
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            self.__setattr__(k, v)
        
        self.c = kwargs.get('c', 1)
        self.d = kwargs.get('d', 2)
        print(self.b(self.c,self.d))
    
    def b(self,c,d):
        return(c+d)
```

Al utilizar la clase de la siguiente forma

```
prueba = A(f=5, g=2)
```

El código imprime `3` pero el método `b` aún puede sobreescribirse

Otra forma que he visto de procesar los kwargs es con `if`

```
class A(object):
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        if 'c' in kwargs:
            self.c = kwargs['c']
        else:
            self.c = 1
            
        if 'd' in kwargs:
            self.d = kwargs['d']
        else:
            self.d = 2
            
        if 'b' in kwargs:
            raise ValueError('El argumento "b" no es aceptable porque existe un método interno con ese nombre')
        
        print(self.b(self.c,self.d))
    
    def b(self,c,d):
        return(c+d)
```

A pesar de que funciona y permite proteger los métodos internos, no creo que sea la mejor opción, en especial si hay muchos argumentos que procesar

¿Cuál sería la forma correcta de utilizar, validar y procesar `**kwargs`? y ¿Por qué?

**Edición:** A continuación agrego la idea en pseudo código de cómo funciona una de las clases que tengo y el por qué necesito encontrar una forma correcta de utilizar, validar y procesar los **kwargs**

```
Class Segment(object):
    def __init__ (self, tipo):
        self.type = tipo
        #Inicialización de los puntos que serán utilizados para generar el SVG según el tipo de segmento que se desee crear
    
    # Los kwargs que recibe _group vienen del método plot, según hayan sido configurados por el usuario
    def _group(self, **kwargs):
        # Se agrupan varios elementos tipo "Polygon", "Polyline" y "Text" según el segmento que se desee crear
    
    # Al desear mostrar la imagen del segmento seleccionado se puede seleccionar el ángulo de rotación del SVG y algunas otras
    # propiedades como colores, ancho de borde, tamaño y fuente del texto, etc...
    # Estas propieadades se deben pasar al método _group() ya que se deben aplicar a los polígonos y otros elementos del SVG
    # La librería svgwrite recibe kwargs para algunas de las propiedades que se pueden configurar
    def plot(self, angle = 0, **kwargs):
        # Se crea el SVG que será mostrado y el "Drawing" que podría ser guardado
        self._dwg = svgwrite.Drawing(.....)
        # Se crea el grupo, aquí se pueden configurar los colores, bordes, fuente y tamaño del texto de los poligonos y otros elementos del SVG
        # El grupo no puede ser creado antes de generar la imagen porque deben incluir todas las propiedades (Colores, etc...) que configure
        # el usuario al utilizar el método plot()
        g = self._group(self.type, angle, **kwargs)
        
        # Se agrega el grupo recién creado al "Drawing" para ser mostrado
        self._dwg.add(g)

        # Se muestra el SVG si se utiliza JupyterLab
        Display(self._dwg)
        
        # Se retorna self para poder encadenar el método save()
        return self

    def save(self, nombre = 'Segmento.svg'):
        self._dwg.saveas(nombre)


# Los argumentos "seg_body_fill" y "seg_body_stroke" deben pasarse del método plot al método _group
# y del mpetodo _group a cada una de las funciones que generan los diferentes elementos del SVG
# estas funciones también reciben kwargs para configurar color, tamaño, campo visual, tamaño y tipo de fuente, etc...
Segment('aa').plot(45, seg_body_fill = '#ff0000', seg_body_stroke = '#eeeeee')
```

Pero también hay otras clases "Track", "Loop" y "Assembly", cada una construyendo un nivel superior, por ejemplo, un Track es un conjunto de elementos de clase Segment y por lo tanto al hacer `plot()` en la instancia de la clase Track, es necesario pasar todas las propiedades a cada uno de los elementos de la clase Segment. Assembly está por encima de Track, es decir, un Assembly puede tener varios Track y por lo tanto al hacer `plot()` en una instancia de la clase Assembly, todos las propiedades deben pasarse a cada elemento de la clase Track y a su vez a cada elemento de la clase Segment de cada elemento Track.

El inconveniente es que son tantos parámetros que crear un argumento por cada parámetro creo no sería óptimo, en especial si en un futuro las clases son modificadas o se agregan más elementos al SVG

Comment: Buen día, he visto que dos personas votaron que la pregunta es basada en opiniones, pero no estoy buscando opiniones, debe haber algún lineamientos o guía de cómo debe hacerse de forma correcta, eso es lo que busco, saber la forma correcta de hacerlo

Comment: Quizas deberías aclarar para qué necesitas hacerlo. No solo porque probablemente la forma correcta dependa de tu caso, sino porque además no parece una necesidad muy común, y más bien parece un [problema XY](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY)

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, voy a editar la pregunta y escribir un poco sobre la aplicación que tengo y el por qué necesito saber como hacerlo de forma correcta

Comment: @abulafia, he agregado la razón por la que he hecho la pregunta. Las clases que tengo son muy grandes por eso cree el mínimo ejemplo al inicio de la pregunta para demostrar que lo que requiero es una estrategia para procesar los kwargs en diferentes niveles de métodos y clases.

Comment: `**kwargs` se usa cuando necesitas recibir una lista pero te da flojera crearla en la llamada. Asi, en lugar de escribir `sumar([1,2,3])`, escribes solo `sumar(1,2,3)`, y en lugar de `def sumar(lista):` haces `def sumar(**kwargs valor):`

Comment: Gracias @CandidMoe, pero esa no es la pregunta, entiendo para qué sirven los **kwargs, pero quiero saber la forma correcta de procesarlos según lo escrito en la pregunta

Comment: BTW, usar mapas en lugar de atributos y/o parametros con nombres tiene el inconveniente de ser totalmente opaco. Tú miras el código y no tienes idea de cuales son los atributos del objeto ni  que parámetros tiene la llamada, entre otras cosa.

Comment: @CandidMoe Ok, pero en algunos casos necesito pasar los valores 5-6 niveles a diferentes clases y/o métodos, por eso pensé en **kwargs** como una solución para mantener el código "limpio"

Comment: Te recomiendo recorrer las librerías de Python y ver como/en que casos se usa **kwargs en ellas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137115/discussion-between-candid-moe-and-heytalepazguato).

Comment: @CandidMoe, si, es lo que estuve haciendo, de ahí saqué los ejemplos de la pregunta

Comment: @CandidMoe, Gracias por la información, de igual forma he solicitado reapertura de la pregunta ya que por más que he buscado no encuentro alguna fuente que indique como empaquetar y desempaquetar los kwargs de forma "ideal".